# Cypress - how to draw a line using cypress while holding option key on a text file

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, keycode

I need to draw a line using one application tool. I tried code below, it is not working. So basically I need to click on a word while holding option key and then click on another word, it will create a relationship between those two.

Screenshot for example:

[image: Screenshot for example]

here's my code :

```js
cy.contains('Ut enim ad').trigger('keydown', { altKey: true }).trigger('mouseenter', { force: true });
cy.contains('Ut enim ad').trigger('mousedown', { force: true });      
cy.contains('quis nostrud').trigger('mousedown', { force: true }); 
cy.contains('quis nostrud').trigger('mouseup', { force: true });   
cy.contains('quis nostrud').trigger('keyup', { altKey: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky with drawing tests in Cypress, would really need to see the HTML and the exact events that are used by the app to follow the mouse.

Even so, it seems you would need to use shift or ctrl to define the endpoints of the "add a line" action

```js
cy.contains('Ut enim ad').click({ctrlKey:true})
cy.contains('quis nostrud').click()
```